# iplot library Not Displaying my visualization

Tags: python

I am trying to visualize my DataFrame using iplot. I have imported pandas and cufflinks as pd and cf respectively. The problem I am facing is whenever I call `iplot` using my DataFrame and run it i.e. `df.iplot()`, I don't see my visualization. Can someone explain why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `cufflinks` and `chart-studio`  as `DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iplot'`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())

df.plot()
plt.show()
df.iplot()
```

In contrast, you can use `pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
fig = df.plot()
fig.show()
```

Comment: It didn’t work

Comment: I run the code before I post it. So, try `plotly`.

Comment: Could you please tell me what error you get?

Comment: I have discovered the problem already. Thank you so much

Comment: The problem was that init_notebook_mode(connected = True) I changed it to False